# Apply function to pandas dataframe to scan a list in a column/cell depending on an other column/cell

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, row

I am faced with a problem while scanning rows from a `pandas` data frame. I have some input data in a data frame that are fix (columns are `Time`, `ID` and `frames`). Now I try to get some results from it. With every timestamp I get one or more LIN ID's and with every LIN ID I get one LIN frame with 8 data bytes as string. This data string represents the raw values from some sensors.

Now I want to scan each row find the LIN ID and its corresponding LIN frame, calculate the raw sensor value and store this value in the `pandas` dataframe as new column. My problem is that I get a list of IDs and a list of LIN Frames in each row. My question is: How can I get the correct values out of these list in a cell? Is it possible with `apply` or is there an easier way?

I hope I described it good enough, cause I'm new to this forum and a `python` beginner. Could someone take a look at the following source code and show me the right way?

Here is a picture of the expected output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBGaG.jpg

```
from binascii import unhexlify

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sys


def getVal(data, btn):
    '''
    Calculate 2-byte hex data to float value LSB first
    '''
    try:
        mydata = bytearray(unhexlify(data))
        b = (btn - 1) * 2

        # swap byteorder
        val = (mydata[b + 1] << 8) + mydata[b]

    except:
        val = np.nan

    return val


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # I get data in this form
    # 'Time':    one set of data every 7ms
    # 'ID':      list of LIN Ids at each timestamp
    # 'frames' : list of frames at each timestamp

    #=======================================================================
    # This has the correct input data, but did not works
    #=======================================================================
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'Time': [0, 0.007, 0.014, 0.021, 0.028, 0.035, 0.042, 0.049, 0.056, 0.063],
                        'ID': [['11', '12', '14'], ['12'], ['13'], ['14'], [], [], ['11'], ['12'], ['13'], ['14']],
                        'frames': [['25186617A819AB19', 'B31A031A5F1ADF1A', 'AD18D517DD150000'], ['07D06617a719ab19'], ['0BB86617a719ab19'], ['0FA06617a719ab19'], [], [], ['33186617a719ab19'], ['33186617a719ab19'], ['33186617a719ab19'], ['33186617a719ab19']]})

    # build names Btn_0_raw up to Btn_15_raw as column names
    names = ["Btn_{}_raw".format(x) for x in range(16)]

    # LIN IDs to search for
    linIDs = ['11', '12', '13', '14']

    # show values to check they are correct
#     print names
#     print df1["Time"].head()
#     print df1.iloc[:]
#     print df1["frames"].head()
#              

    error = False

    # #loop over 16 buttons
    for btn in range(16):  

        # show that all variables are correct; 
        # use constant hex data for each button group of 4 button; 
        # values are (100,200,300,400) (0x0064,0x00c8,0x012c,0x0190)
        print "{0}:{1}, ID({2}), bytePos({3}), demo value:{4}".format(btn, names[btn], linIDs[btn / 4], (btn % 4) + 1, getVal('6400C8002c019001', (btn % 4) + 1)) 

        try:
            df1[names[btn]] = df1['frames'].where(linIDs[btn / 4] in df1['ID'], np.nan).apply(lambda x: getVal(x, (btn % 4) + 1))
        except ValueError as e:
            print " Value error :", e
            error = True

    if not error:
        df1.to_excel('test-1.xls')



    #===========================================================================
    # An example that works, but unfortunately this input data are incorrect
    #===========================================================================
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'Time': [0, 0.007, 0.014, 0.021, 0.028, 0.035, 0.042, 0.049, 0.056, 0.063],
                            'ID': ['11', '12', '13', '14', np.nan, np.nan, '11', '12', '13', '14'],
                            'frames': ['6400C8002c019001', '6500C9002d019101', '6600CA002e019201', '6700CB002F019301', '', '', '6400C8002c019001', '6500C9002d019101', '6600CA002e019201', '6700CB002F019301']
                            })

    error = False

    # loop over 16 buttons
    for btn in range(16):  

        # show that all variables are correct; 
        print "{0}:{1}, ID({2}), bytePos({3}), demo value:{4}".format(btn, names[btn], linIDs[btn / 4], (btn % 4) + 1, getVal('6400C8002c019001', (btn % 4) + 1)) 

        try:
            df2[names[btn]] = df2['frames'].where(df2['ID'] == linIDs[btn / 4] , np.nan).apply(lambda x: getVal(x, (btn % 4) + 1))
            print df2[names[btn]]
        except ValueError as e:
            print " Value error :", e
            error = True

    if not error:
        df2.to_excel("test-2.xls")
```

Comment: Your question is hard to follow, could you improve it a bit? 1) provide example input with desired output 2) explain "correct input data, but did not works" and "works, but … data are incorrect" – what is definition of "correct" and what do you men by "does not work". Without that it would be difficult to help you

Comment: Hi black_fm, thank you for your answer. 1) Correct Input data is the format of dataframe df1. Each cell of the column ID has lists with no, one or more than one element. Each element has a corresponding Frame in column Frames. If i run that example I get the following error: Value error : Array conditional must be same shape as self. The second dataframe has only one element in each cell of column ID. With this Input data I get nearly the expected output data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to show how to split your data into columns corresponding to buttons. I modified input data to be able to fit it nicely in the screen:

```
import pandas as pd

names = ["B_{}".format(x) for x in range(16)]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'Time': [0, 0.007, 0.014, 0.021, 0.028, 0.035, 0.042, 0.049, 0.056, 0.063],
                    'ID': [['11', '12', '14'], ['12'], ['13'], ['14'], [], [], ['11'], ['12'], ['13'], ['14']],
                    'frames': [['2518', 'B31A', 'AD18'], ['07D0'], ['0BB8'], ['0FA0'], [], [], ['3318'], ['3318'], ['3318'], ['3318']]})

df_new = pd.DataFrame(df1, columns=['Time'] + names)
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    # copying whatever data you already have in the old dataframe
    df_new.loc[index] = row
    # for every button ID set value in corresponding column
    for ID, value in zip(row['ID'], row['frames']):
        df_new.loc[index, names[int(ID)]] = value
```

df1

```
             ID   Time              frames
0  [11, 12, 14]  0.000  [2518, B31A, AD18]
1          [12]  0.007              [07D0]
2          [13]  0.014              [0BB8]
3          [14]  0.021              [0FA0]
4            []  0.028                  []
5            []  0.035                  []
6          [11]  0.042              [3318]
7          [12]  0.049              [3318]
8          [13]  0.056              [3318]
9          [14]  0.063              [3318]
```

df_new (showing only non-empty columns)

```
    Time  B_11  B_12  B_14  B_13
0  0.000  2518  B31A  AD18   NaN
1  0.007   NaN  07D0   NaN   NaN
2  0.014   NaN   NaN   NaN  0BB8
3  0.021   NaN   NaN  0FA0   NaN
4  0.028   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
5  0.035   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
6  0.042  3318   NaN   NaN   NaN
7  0.049   NaN  3318   NaN   NaN
8  0.056   NaN   NaN   NaN  3318
9  0.063   NaN   NaN  3318   NaN
```

In `df_new.loc[index, names[int(ID)]] = value` step you can apply `getVal` to `value` and this, I believe, will produce the result you need.

Comment: thanks a lot for the right way. It works. I apply getVal to value 4 times cause of 4 Buttons per value and change the indexer for names. to:     for i in range(4):
                 df_new.loc[index, names[(int(ID)-11)*4+i]] = getVal(value, i+1) By the way, Is there a chance to speed it up, cause in normal case I have to scan up to 20 files with more than 800 lines each file?

Comment: @Thomas Made a small change - when creating new dataframe I use the original one to set the index. This way pandas does not need to extend dataframe on each iteration, this should speed things up. There probably is a better way but I can't think of it from the top of my head. How time-sensitive are you? If that's something you are going to run once a day then even 5 minutes processing time would not be too bad. But if you run it every minute, then you surely will have to be faster than that :D

Comment: Setting the index is the solution. I insert df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(columns=names)]) to create the columns before I iterate the rows. So the code runs fast enough. It's more a comfort than  a time critical thing. Thank you very much for your help.